# Trouble with null characters in Arduino

Tags: null, serial-port, arduino

I am trying to write an Arduino program that will translate a text string transmitted through the Serial Monitor to Morse code. This is the offending function:

```
void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()){
    char inChar = Serial.read();
    input += inChar;
    if (inChar == '\0'){  
      Serial.print("END!");
      stringComplete = true;
    }
  }
}
```

It should take characters from the serial input one by one, adding them to the input string until it reaches the end of the serial input (ie a null character). For some reason the 'if' statement won't execute for

```
inChar == '\0'
```

But if I replace '\0' with an arbitrary character as in

`inChar == 'g'`

It executes just fine. Am I somehow calling the null character '\0' wrong?

Comment: What you want is read word by word, or letter by letter and determine the end of the entire message?

Comment: Yeah, something like that. The function reads each incoming character and appends it to String input. When it finds a null character I want `stringComplete` to be true, which is the cue for a separate function to take over.

Comment: What I think is that you think that you read all characters in the while loop, Am I right? The truth is that only a character is read by each call to the `loop()` method, so, you can set `stringComplete = true` when `Serial.available() == 0`.

Comment: Great! I have posted the answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I think is that you think that you read all characters in the while loop, Am I right? The truth is that only a character is read by each call to the `loop()` method, so, you can set `stringComplete = true` when `Serial.available() == 0`.